# how to detect whether a uri is allow by shiro or extract controller name from uri

Tags: grails, shiro, url-mapping

i have a uri such as someController/someAction?param1=aa&param2=bb

is there some method of grails can extract controller name and action name from this uri.

or shiro has any method to detect this uri is permitted?

---

i have a domain Menu(name,url), and now want to get the menu list which is permitted for current user.

url such as /auth/login(may be mapping as user:login), /user/login

so 2 days ago i ask this question.

now i change the menu to (name,controller,action,param),and filter the menulist like this:

```
def subject = SecurityUtils.subject;
menuList.each{
  if(it.permission){
     def perm = shiroPermissionResolver.resolvePermission("${it.permission.controller}:${it.permission.action}")
     def isPermitted = subject.isPermitted(perm)
     println "$isPermitted -> ${it.permission.controller}:${it.permission.action}"
  }
}
```

---

sorry for my poor english,and thanks for reply.

btw,here is another question of how to cache shiro:
[how to use cache permissions in grails shiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425283/how-to-use-cache-permissions-in-grails-shiro)

---

To proflux:
so what do u think is the better way to store menulist? 
cause:

1. it need to show different menu to user due to their permissions.
2. sometime we update a webapp, but want to show menu to user later.
   so we only need to change such as a menu.visible. (better than change    hard code cfg or source).
3. we areusing extjs to show the menu(so nav plugin cant use).

Comment: Sorry because I can't get the question, could you give me an example?

Comment: i just think that if i have a url,how to change it to controller+action. maybe /auth/login is mapping to user:login

Comment: Can you help me understand why you're storing your user interface menu in a domain class?

Answer (score 3):

Shiro uses the convention of `$controller:$action` for permissions.  You have two options:

1. Use the Shiro Tags
2. Use the Shiro API directly

In the first case, in your GSP you can add something like:

```
<shiro:hasPermission permission="someController:someAction">
     <g:link...>
</shiro:hasPermission>
<shiro:lacksPermission permission="someController:someAction">
     No link
</shiro:lacksPermission>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `<g:if...>` tag and use the

```
SecurityUtils.subject.isPermitted("someController:someAction")
```

method to directly check if the user has the necessary permission.

For more info, check out the [Grails Shiro Tag Library Source](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/grails-plugins/grails-shiro/trunk/grails-app/taglib/org/apache/shiro/grails/ShiroTagLib.groovy?r=HEAD) and the [Shiro API docs](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/).

Comment: thanks for reply. i just think that if i have a url,how to change it to controller+action. maybe /auth/login is mapping to user:login

Comment: Where in your application do you need to make this check?  I have used Shiro and Grails quite a bit and if you end up in this situation it's probably because you're not taking full advantage the features Shiro and/or Grails has to offer.  If you can post some more details I can probably help you figure out where the problem is.  Post the piece of code where you want to make this test and we'll go from there...